# Saving the text in notes and email the text file

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

I am working on application where you are able to save the text from TextView to "Notes" and then use the "Notes" to email that text to your ID, send message etc. First, Can we access apples default "Notes" SDK. If not, Is there any similar API exists that I can use for my app. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: You cannot open the `Notes` app, it doesn't has any UL scheme. Can you clarify a bit, what are trying to do?

Comment: No, I want to do it programatically. Need to access from my app. One option I found is "Evernote SDK". Is there any other SDK's?

Answer (score 0):

"Evernote SDK" is one option that can be used for this purpose. [https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-ios/blob/master/Getting_Started.md][1]